# Meaning of “City Lites”

Tags: meaning, title, paul-beatty, the-sellout

I'm reading [*The Sellout*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sellout_(novel)) by Paul Beatty.

One of the sections is titled: "City Lites"

The first thing that comes to my mind is Charlie Chaplin's famous movie. But what else can be understood from it?

Comment: Maybe it's a reference to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/City_Lights_Bookstore ?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you think it is a reference to something outside the book>

Comment: @Spagirl I'm not sure.  "City Lites: An Interlude" is the complete title and book’s satirical take on the concept of “sister cities” lampoons the somewhat childish nature of international relations. The idea that cities would have a matchmaking service shows that relations between different cities and countries can be no less petty than the relationships between individual people looking to go on first dates.

Comment: @kimchilover That's rather unlikely. City Lights is in San Francisco, approximately 350 miles away from the setting of Beatty's novel, which is Los Angeles. The NorCal / SoCal rivalry is intense; denizens of neither city would appreciate its being mistaken for the other.